# Proving simplicial homology is preserved on mapping?

Tags: modules, homology-cohomology, simplicial-stuff, simplicial-complex, diagram-chasing

Assume we have a the $\mathbb Z\text{ modules}$ $S1 \equiv (F, E, V)$ with boundary maps $(\partial_{FE}: F \rightarrow E$, $\partial_{EV}: E \rightarrow V)$, with the condition that $\partial_{EV} \circ \partial_{FE} = 0$ (homology condition). We interpret this as the description of a simplicial complex.

Similarly, we have another space $S_2 \equiv (F', E', V')$ with associated boundary maps $\partial_{F'E'}: F' \rightarrow E', \partial_{E'V'}: E' \rightarrow V'$ which also satisfy the homology condition $\partial_{E'V'} \circ \partial_{F'E'} = 0$.

Now, I describe a "mapping" between these two simplicial complexes, given by $(f: F \rightarrow F', e: E \rightarrow E', v: V \rightarrow V')$, such that the diagram commutes:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
F & \xrightarrow{\partial_{FE}} & E &\xrightarrow{\partial_{EV}} & V \\
f\downarrow & & e\downarrow & & v\downarrow \\ 
F' & \xrightarrow{\partial_{F'E'}} & E' &\xrightarrow{\partial_{E'V'}} & V' \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

At this point, I would like to conclude that the mapping $(f, e, v)$ can only simplify the homology group. Formally, I wish to show that:

$$
\text{there exists a surjective abelian group homomorphism }  \phi: Ker(\partial_{EV})/Im(\partial_{FE}) \twoheadrightarrow Ker(\partial_{E'V'})/Im(\partial_{F'E'})
$$

I feel like I know nothing in the theory of exact sequences that will let me quickly prove this. However, I feel strongly that there *must* be a gadget that lets me get this quickly? I'm terribly sorry if this is something 'standard'. I self taught myself this material, so my understanding is quite scattered.

Comment: The way you formulated your question it is not true, take the first complex to be all 0 groups and the second one having nontrivial homology...

Comment: Mh, I now know how I want to 'fix' the question : I want all $(f, e, v)$ to be surjective. Do I edit the question, or post a new one? I'm unsure about the etiquette here. @M.Van Thanks for drawing my attention to the bug :)

Comment: There's a canonical map between your two homology groups, but it need not be surjective even when $f$, $e$ and $v$ are. See texts on homological algebra for the long exact sequence of homology associated to as short exact sequence of complexes.

Comment: @AnginaSeng Can you point me to precisely what theorem helps me construct this canonical map? I will be glad to accept an answer that points out references!

Comment: Look at p.116 onwards in Hatcher's  *Algebraic Topology*. @SiddharthBhat